# docker image runs ok locally but in ECS I get a message: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I've a weird error, I'm trying to run a python script in ECS, the dockerfile is pretty basic:

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY . /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD  ["python", "./get_historical_data.py"]
```

building this in my local machine works perfect,

`docker run --network=host historical-price`

I uploaded this image to ECR and run  on ECS, a basic config, just set container name, pointing the Image to my ECR repo and set some environment variables...when I run this I get

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

but (really weird) if I enter in the EC2 server and run the container manually

```
docker run -it  -e TICKER='SOL/USDT' -e EXCHANGE='BINANCE' -e DB_HOST='xxx' -e DB_NAME='xxx' -e DB_PASSWORD='xxx' -e DB_PORT='xxx' -e DB_USER='xxx' xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/xxx:latest /bin/bash
```

I can see this running ok...

I've tried several dockerfiles, using

```
CMD python ./get_historical_data.py
```

or using python3 command instead of python

also I tried to skip the CMD command in the Dockerfile and add this in the ECS task definition

nothing work...

I really don't know what can be happen here because the last week I ran a similar task and this worked perfectly, hope you can help me

thank you, please let me know if you need more details

Comment: can you try `CMD ["python", "./get_historical_data.py"]`

Comment: @Korgen yes, that was my first try and didn't work...